# VB Datarepeater control in Visual Studio 2010 - currentItemIndex updated before textbox leave event when using mouse

Tags: datarepeater

I'm using a datarepeater control, version 10.0 in visual studio 2010.  The CurrentItemIndex seems to update before the textbox leave event when I use the mouse to move to the next row. So, when I retrieve the value from the textbox, I don't now what ItemIndex it is associated with. This doesn't happen when the keyboard is used to move to the next row.  Anyone see this happen. Version 9.0 on the datarepeater did work this way.

Answer (score 0):

To answer you directly, here are some C# snippets.  I'm assuming that you already have the TextBox object (or other control) as implied in your question.  I will also assume that you're inside an event handler (e.g. TextChanged).  If you haven't already done it, you need to use the object sender parameter and not the design-time declared TextBox control (i.e. do not use TextBox1, or similar object) because it will just refer to the DataRepeaterItem template control and not the individual control for the data row you're interested in.

```
    TextBox itemTextBox = sender as TextBox;

    //* DataRepeaterItem is a control which contains other controls for each data "row"
    DataRepeaterItem drItem = itemTextBox.Parent as DataRepeaterItem;

    //* Retrieve the particular data item
    int idx = drItem.ItemIndex;

    //* If DataRepeater is bound to a BindingSource, for example, 
    //*   one can retrieve the underlying data item
    object dataItem = myBindingSource.List[idx];
```

I've experienced various bugs and challenges with control focus and data updates with the DataRepeater.  There is no guarantee of exactly which order the events fire: Leave, LostFocus, CurrentItemChanged, etc. And as you've observed, it differs depending on whether you use the mouse within the DataRepeater or to/from another control on the form or using the keyboard.  There may indeed be an established algorithm, but I have observed differences from documentation.  The situation is complicated when the data-handling framework (e.g. BindingSource, CurrencyManager) also subscribes to these events and updates things out of order from what you might expect or want.  I don't have a suggestion on how to handle these issues, but I hope the code above can at least get you access to the particular index and data for the control you're in.